# Problem of doing preprocessing for testing set in GridSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I use 20% of the data set as my testing set and use GridSearchCV to implement K-fold cross-validation to tune hyperparameters.

By using a pipeline, we can put the column transformer and the machine learning algorithm into GridSearchCV together. If I set up a 5 fold cross-validation for GridSearchCV, the function will use 5 different training and validation sets to train and validate each combination of hyperparameters. As I know, GridSearchCV uses the mean of 5 fold scores to choose the best model.

Then my question is, how does it transform the testing set?

I'm very confused about this because to avoid data leakage, we should use only the training set to fit the transformer, but in this case, we have 5 different training sets and I don't know which one the GridSearchCV function uses to fit and transform the validation and testing set.

My code is given below

```
X_other, X_test, y_other, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = i)
kf = KFold(n_splits = 4, shuffle = True, random_state = i)
pipe = Pipeline(steps = [("preprocessor", preprocessor),("model", ML_algo)])

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = pipe, param_grid=param_grid,
                    scoring = make_scorer(mean_squared_error, greater_is_better=False, 
                    squared=False),cv=kf, return_train_score = True, n_jobs=-1, verbose=False)

grid.fit(X_other, y_other)
test_score = mean_squared_error(y_test, grid.predict(X_test), squared=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

short answer: there is no data leakage, **test set is not used (and should not be used) for training the model in your code.**

long answer: k fold cross-validation randomly divided your **`X_other& y_other`(training set)** into k splits, for each iteration of cross-validation, k-1 fold of data is used to train the model while this model is then evaluated with the 1 fold left using the metric you specified in `scoring=`. (refer to the below picture from sklearn for details:https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation)

After finding the best set of hyperparameters by `GridSearchCV()`, **all training set data is used in training a final model with the found hyperparameters**, then, `X_test,y_test` (test set) can be transformed by this model. Note that in this process, `X_test,y_test` is not used and should not be used other than in the final prediction.

[image: pre]